# Can we say that everywhere where it makes sense $\log_0 x=0^x$? Are they equal, the function is self-inverse? If so, what is deep intuition behind it?

Tags: matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, intuition, big-picture, hypercomplex-numbers

It makes little reason to speak about $0^x$ and $\log_0 x$ on the set of real numbers, but in matrices, it seems, the expressions coincide, for instance,

$0^ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)=\log_0 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right),$

where $0$ is meant to be zero matrix.
Since all hypercomplex numbers can be represented in matrix form, logarithm with base zero makes sense there as well, and its equivalence to the powers of zero still holds. For instance, in [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_numbers) we have

$0^{1/2+j/2}=1/2-j/2= \log_0 (1/2+j/2),$

$0^{1/2-j/2}=1/2+j/2= \log_0 (1/2-j/2).$

As such, I wonder, whether it would be sensible to claim $\log_0 x=0^x$ in all other contexts? Is there some proof or expansion that would show this is the case?

I asked a similar question on math.stackexchange but was heavily downvoted and the question was closed because, as some users claimed "logarithm with zero base has no sense".

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4266584/87355

Comment: What are your definitions of $\log_0 x$ and $0^x$ for matrices $x$?

Comment: @HjalmarRosengren for $0^x$ I used MatrixFunction in Mathematica, which I think uses Jordan decomposition. In matrix form of split-complex numbers it gives an explicit formula for an arbitrary function of a split-complex number: $f(a+bj)=\frac{1}{2} (f(a-b)+f(a+b))+\frac{j}{2} (f(a+b)-f(a-b))$. Inserting here $f(z)=0^z$ and assuming $0^0=1$ we get the explicit expression for split-complex numbers. Regarding logarithm, I considered it as an inverse function of $0^z$.

Comment: Real numbers can be viewed as $1\times1$ matrices, so surely you can't prove *more* about general matrices than about real numbers.

Comment: @LSpice where did I say one should prove more? On real numbers this equation also works, just less obvious. When proving something about zero divisors, it is obvious better to use general matrices than a set with no zero divisors.

Comment: Such a question should include a definition.  Something more than `MatrixFunction` in Mathematica.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405359/can-we-say-that-everywhere-where-it-makes-sense-log-0-x-0x-are-they-equal#comment1039064_405359), you say "It makes little sense to speak about $0^x$ and $\log_0 x$ on the set of real numbers, but in matrices, it seems, the expressions coincide".  That seemed to be saying that you could do something with general matrices that you couldn't do with real numbers.

Comment: @LSpice on real numbers we can only observe that $0^0=1$ and $\log_0 0=1$ (as inverse to $0^1=0$). We also can see that $0^5=0$ and $\log_0 5=0$ (the later if we believe Wolfram Alphla https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5B0%2C5%5D ) If we take matrices with non-tivial zero divisors, we can see more coincidences. The question is, whether it happens for all zero divisors and other values, for which the expressions make sense.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar not directly connected to this question, but an old expression for $0^x$ by me in terms of Zeta and Gamma functions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070070/integral-representation-of-fx-0x I wonder, whether it can be used for generalizations to matrix spaces.

Comment: From $0^5 = 0$ we get $\log_0 0 = 5$.  This tells us nothing about $\log_0 5$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar yes, but in limit we have $\lim_{b\to0^+}\log_b 5=0$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5Bx%2C5%5D But yes, it is confusing why Wolfram Alpha gives this value (while avoiding much less controversial $0^0=1$)

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Basically, the both functions have graphics, representing a 90 degrees angle along x and y semi-axes, but the value y=1 at x=0 is more justified in the both functions (though their graphics are vertical at x=0). We cannot see more in real or complex numbers. On zero divisors we see more symmetry.

Answer (score 4):

Experimenting with Maple, it seems Maple's definition of $0^A$, where $A$ is
a square matrix,  will be:

$\bullet\;$If $A$ is diagonalizable, Say $A = Q^{-1} D Q$ with
$D = \operatorname{diag}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, then
$$
0^D = \operatorname{diag}\big(0^{a_1},\dots,0^{a_n}\big)\\
0^A = Q^{-1} 0^D Q
$$
Here $0^x = 0$ if $\operatorname{Re}(x) > 0$ and $0^0 = 1$.  Some others like $0^{-1}$ and $0^i$ are undefined.

$\bullet\;$ If $A$ is not diagonalizable, then $0^A$ is undefined.  For example $0^A$ is undefined if
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} ,
$$
even though it is a zero divisor.  [Hidden reason: $0^x$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.]

---

I did not get Maple to do anything with $\log_0 A$.

Comment: Yes, not all zero divisors give values. For instance, $0^{j/2+1/2}=1/2-j/2$, but $0^{j/2-1/2}$ is undefined (infinite).

Comment: Try $\log_b A$ and then insert $b=0$.

Comment: By the way, what happens if to invert the exponentiation operation? It not it symmetric?